How to disable "Text Copied" pop up when copying text (Debian 12)
This might be a very basic question but I have tried searching this on google for a long time without any success. I recently installed Debian 12 (using Gnome 43 DE). When I try to copy any text, there is a popup (shown in the screenshot) and a sound that is played. Is there any way to disable the pop up and the sound?
Turning on "Do Not Disturb" does prevent the pop up from showing but then this also hides all other notifications. I tried going to "Settings>Notifications" but there is no option for turning off this "Text Copied" pop-up.


This answer might be a little late, but i had the same issue and for me it turned out to be the pano clipboard extension sending those notifications. So opening Extensions and going to the Pano-Settings let me disable "Send notification on copy" and "Play an audio on copy".

Also, the other answer provided just allows you to change overall notification settings, so it might not be what you're looking for

Install dconf Editor:
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor

Open dconf Editor from your applications menu.
Navigate to the following path:
/org/gnome/desktop/notifications/application/gnome-shell/.

Look for the setting you want to change.
Change the value from priority or critical to low / remove.
